# LibGDX FreeTypeFontGenerator

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, freetype

I've created LibGDX project with latest Gradle based setup application v1.1.0.
When I created I didn't add FreeType extension on the project.
Now I need it. How can I add it to already created project?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [libGDX's wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle)

> **FreeTypeFont Gradle**
>
> Core Dependency:
>
> - compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
>
> Desktop Dependency:
>
> - compile    "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
>
> Android Dependency:
>
> - compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
> - natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
> - natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
> - natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
>
> iOS Dependency:
>
> - compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
> - natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

Don't forget to refresh your dependencies ;)

Comment: I added to my conf file, but I still cannot import FreeTypeFontGenerator

Comment: You probably need to rebuild the Gradle model, or "reimport the dependencies" if that makes more sense.

Comment: @KiKo I think you can do something like right click on your project > "gradle" > "refresh dependencies"

Comment: I guess it made more sense to Gradle as well. I still have to learn about the terms it uses and how to-s, heh.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a complete build.gradle with all the modules, you can see which one is FreeType related and just add it to your gradle configuration.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
        classpath 'com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.9'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'klaxon-game'
        gdxVersion = '1.1.0'
        roboVMVersion = '0.0.13'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: please note that since June 12 2014, there have been new modules added such as `Ashley` ( https://github.com/libgdx/ashley/wiki/How-to-use-Ashley ) .